# HTML <header>/<footer> most common CSS practice

Tags: html, css, header, footer

What's the best style, for styling 'main' header (or footer) in CSS?

I've styled just like:
`header { ... }`

but then I remembered, that there can be more than 1 header in html...

1. So I rewrote:
   `body > header { ... }`

But it's rather not beautiful. To write in several places smth like `body > header .search { ... }`

2.nd possibility:
`<header class="main-header">`

But it's also not very beautiful.

3. Of course, it's possible just to ignore, that there can be several headers (footers). But I markup html/css not for myself, so it's possible, that smb will add new header/footer elements in html.

So, what is the best style? That is used in great companies like Google, StackOverflow, Microsoft, IBM and so on.

**Hey! I've an idea! What's about to write for main header/footer simple `header { ... }` and for special headers/footers smth like `.some-element header { ... }`? Now it's obvious for me, that it's the best style. Am I right?**

Comment: Have you checked their CSS yourself?

Comment: 'They' have many sites with different markup. So I wanted to know from experienced progers, what are the best practices these companies recommend

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s important that we’re all focusing on the **performance improvements** that our users will really notice. So it is not about how beautiful it is rather than an **optimized** one.

For CSS, there are several things that we have to consider. In case of selectors, we have to focus on how CSSOM would construct (You can learn more from [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAwxTw4SYaPmKmNX-INgcxQWf30KuWa_A), a course provided by team Udacity).

For a matter of performance, use classes instead of tags. Also, usage of two or more rules(like `div>p>span`) will cause more time to render the page.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard about BEM? Which stands for block element modifier, that help you achieve a reusable component. I think you should use that, it will make your code as if style and a document ready.

more [here](http://getbem.com/)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure that all my customers will be happy with it. What do you think about it?

Comment: I think you should consider it, It's more clean that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is really about what do you prefer. I think the most simple and easy to read way could be the attribute selector.

```
header[main] {/*something*/}
```

Plus this:

```
<header main>Main header</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest like as below, assuming you are using html5. keep as simple as possible instead to make it complicated. Also keep second level hierarchy as possible to read a code and faster css processing.

> ```
> header{
>  /* enter your css properties */
> }
> header p{
> }
> footer{
>  /* enter your css properties */
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply write css code to write like this
 **header { }**
 or if you have many header on the dom then select the first child of the **header:first-child {}**
or you can write **header:nth-child(1) {}**

Hope it was help you

Thanks